# Browse comment history of my responses to Amazon Customer Reviews

Tags: amazon

I'd like to review the insightful and witty comments I've left in response to customer reviews. I've poked around the Your Account page and I'm finding nothing.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sign into your Amazon account, under the Community sub heading in the Personalisation section on the main Your Account page (towards the bottom of the page) there is a link for "See All My Reviews".

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'm looking for my comments to other people's reviews, not my own reviews.

Comment: Amazon seems to have recently [moved/further hidden] reviews and comments; I don't find them where slogical directs me.

Answer (score 1):

Visit https://www.amazon.com/profile ! Under "Community activity", I see my reviews, and as I recall, sometimes I see my reviews and comments there.  Maybe I changed my comment privacy settings and that's why they're not listed?

Amazon seems to have recently [moved/further hidden] reviews and comments; I don't find them where slogical points us. For me, this link directly brings up my reviews: https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=16465311. YMMV.

Comment: Amazon hid them a bit further away again.  The second (direct) link is now no more useful than the first.